# Combine multiline to one line with proper format

Tags: text-processing

I have a file say FILE1.txt contains below data:-

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
```

I need the output in another file as FILE2 as:-

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
'K', 'L'
```

Note:- New line should start after every 5 characters and not coma after last character.

Answer (score 3):

```
xargs printf "'%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s',\n" <in >out
```

...though that does do the comma after the last character. well, it actually does up to four trailing null fields plus the last comma...

```
sed  -e:n -e'$!N;s/\n/&/4;to' -e$\!bn <in >out \
     -e:o -e"s//', '/g;s/.*/'&',/;$"s/,$//
```

^ that doesn't.

Comment: I didn't knew that we could put rederections in the middle of a command!!!(+1) (I think in this case it does not help readability)

Comment: @JJoao - sure - put em where ever you want. there's some *weird* stuff you can do with `<< heredoc_delimiters` where trailing spaces and aliases are concerned. I don't know what you mean by readability - you read it. I always make an effort to do things a little differently because it's important people understand what *can* work and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p0e 's/.+/"$&",/g; s/,\n$//; s/\n/++$i%5?" ":"\n"/ge'
```